# Updating a mongoose sub-document modifies the original schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I'm trying to store the `location` of a parking `Spot` in a single embedded sub-document for a cleaner object model. I want to have the `coordinates` of a `location` for a `Spot` default to `[]` for every new `Spot`.

When I create a **Schema** as follows:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  Coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
  }
})
```

then embed that **Schema** as a sub-document in `Spot`:

```
var SpotSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: LocationSchema,
    default: LocationSchema
  }
})

var Spot = mongoose.model('Spot', SpotSchema')
```

and then instantiate a `Spot` and try to set it's `coordinates` to some value like `[12, 34]`:

```
var spot = new Spot()
spot.location.coordinates = [12, 34]
```

every new `Spot` I instantiate from then on has it's coordinates defaulted to that value:

```
var anotherSpot = new Spot()
anotherSpot.location.coordinates //returns [12, 34]
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why modifying the property of an instance would modify the original model and by extension every new instance created from it.

### EDIT

The exact same problem happens even without using a sub-document:

```
var SpotSchema = new Schema({
    location: {
        type: {
            coordinates: [Number],
            index: '2dsphere'    
        },
        default: {
            coordinates: []
        }
    }
 })

var Spot = mongoose.model('Spot', SpotSchema')

var spot = new Spot()
spot.location.coordinates = [12, 34]
var anotherSpot = new Spot()
anotherSpot.location.coordinates //returns [12, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (using your last example):

```
var SpotSchema = new Schema({
    location: {
      type        : String,
      coordinates : { 
        $type   : [ Number ],
        default : [],
        index   : '2dsphere'
      },
    }
 }, { typeKey : '$type' })
```

`type` is "reserved" in Mongoose; if you need to create properties with that name, you need to use `typeKey` to tell Mongoose that it should use another identifier to declare the type of a property (in this example, `$type`).

Explained [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey), including a reference to GeoJSON-usage.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work, `spot.location.coordinates` is `undefined`

Comment: I think that `[]` might not be a valid default.

Comment: (or rather, one that doesn't make sense when combined with `index : '2dsphere'`, so Mongoose won't populate it)

Comment: Could you explain to me/point me to an article that would explain why that default doesn't make sense? It seems my google skills are sub-par because I have been searching for more information about mongoose `index`s and `geoJSON` usage in mongoose and clearly I still do not know enough to use them

Comment: If you remove the index declaration, Mongoose _will_ populate the coordinates array, so I guess to Mongoose it doesn't make sense to default to an empty array :-) MongoDB won't index GeoJSON documents with empty or `null` coordinates (documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#sparse-property)), perhaps it's related to that as well.

Comment: Yeah it must be a restriction that mongoose puts on the indexed object to not allow empty arrays which is why the default isn't working